# Should "reCAPTCHA Enterprise site keys" be exposed to the client?

Tags: firebase, recaptcha, firebase-app-check, recaptcha-enterprise

I am using Firebase App Check as part of my web application which I intent to expose to the public (production).

To set it up, I am given a "reCAPTCHA Enterprise site key" which I am asked to use to initialize App Check on the client side like so

```
initializeAppCheck(app, {
  provider: new ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider("my-site-key"),
});
```

**My question is**: would it be be safe to store the site key on the client side, such as in a .env file? Is it okay for this site key to be exposed like that? Is it just a way for google to identify my application, and not a secret key?

Comment: Have a read [on the oficial documentation for this topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api-keys)

Comment: Yes, it's safe to store it client side. The only way bad actors use it is to get a token from a captcha solving service. It's not really useful for anything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things:

1. .env files are not on the client at all.  They just provide values at build time that might eventually get added into the client code if they are referenced by the code.
2. If you're instructed to pass that key into `initializeApp`, then you can't possibly hide the key from the client.  The client necessarily has to get a hold of it somehow in order to provide it to Firebase.  You could go through a lot of trouble to make it *difficult* for someone to get the key, but since the value has to be in the client at some point, it's *impossible* to hide entirely.
3. Recaptcha wouldn't offer much protection if it was easy to subvert by simply getting a hold of a key that must be delivered publicly.  The key clearly not a problem if it lives in the client by design.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying Doug. Those were my suspicions aswell. I will mark this as the answer.